# SQL Server - Storing linebreaks in XML data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is it possible to store non-alphanumeric characters (more specifically line break characters) in a XML data type?

The code below illustrates my problem:

```
declare @a xml
declare @b nvarchar(max)

set @b = '<Entry Attrib="1'+CHAR(13)+'2" />'

print @b

set @a=convert(xml,@b,1)

set @b=convert(nvarchar, @a,1)

print @b
```

The output is:

```
<Entry Attrib="1
2" />
<Entry Attrib="1 2"/>
```

Is there any way I could keep the line break intact?

My actual problem is to store the value in a table (rather than a local variable), so maybe there's some setting for the corresponding XML column in my table that would do the job?

Answer (score 2):

It would not be possible.  The XML Data type is stored as an XML DOM Tree, not a string.

You would have to store it as a varchar instead if you want to keep whitespace.

Comment: Could you point me to some Microsoft official documentation regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

My [answer in the XSLT context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359249/how-to-change-my-xsl-stylesheet-to-properly-allow-carriage-returns/1359396#1359396) should apply here:

> XML parsed entities are often stored
>   in computer files which, for editing
>   convenience, are organized into lines.
>   These lines are typically separated by
>   some combination of the characters
>   carriage-return (#xD) and line-feed
>   (#xA).

So this might be what you are looking for:

```
set @b = '<Entry Attrib="1&#xA;2" />'
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005 and I'm getting the following output:

<Entry Attrib="1&#xA;2" />
<Entry Attrib="1&#x0A;2"/>

Answer (score 0):

White space inside of an XML tag is not considered significant according to the XML specification, and will not be preserved. White space outside of the element will however:

```
declare @a xml
declare @b nvarchar(max)

set @b = '<Entry Attrib="12"> fo'+CHAR(13)+'o</Entry>'
print @b
set @a=convert(xml,@b,1)
set @b=convert(nvarchar(max), @a,1)
print @b
```

will output:

```
<Entry Attrib="12"> fo
o</Entry>
<Entry Attrib="12"> fo
o</Entry>
```

Comment: I get the following error for the second "convert":

Msg 6354, Level 16, State 10, Line 13
Target string size is too small to represent the XML instance

Comment: I got that the first time through too. SQL Server stores nvarchar as 2 bytes for each characters entered + 2 bytes.  Your script sets the storage of @b to 46 bytes (2*22 characters + 2), while mine sets the storage at 66 bytes (2*32 characters + 2).  It seems the optimizer will keep that initial assignment storage allocation in the query plan, so you'll need to use a different variable name, run mine in a new query window.